# C++ downgrade parent pointer to child pointer used as function parameter

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-cast, downgrade

I want use child pointer in place of parent parameter in some function.
Here is simplified code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Parent
{
    private:
        string value;
    public:
        void SetValue(const string& in){ value = in; }
        const string& GetValue() const { return value; }
        virtual ~Parent() {};
};
class Child : public Parent
{
};
void Func(Parent* obj)
{
    Child* cobj = dynamic_cast<Child*>(obj);
    cobj->SetValue("new value");
    delete cobj;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Child* cobj = new Child();
    Func(cobj);
    cout<<"value: "<<cobj->GetValue();
    return 0;
}
```

But it returns `value:`
`Func` does not set the value property. How can I fix the code?
UPDATE1:
But with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Parent
{
    private:
        string value;
    public:
        void SetValue(const string& in){ value = in; }
        const string& GetValue() const { return value; }
        virtual ~Parent() {};
};
class Child : public Parent
{
    private:
        int number;
    public:
        void SetNumber(int in){ number = in; }
        int GetNumber() const { return number; }
};
void Func(Parent* obj)
{
    Child* cobj = dynamic_cast<Child*>(obj);
    cobj->SetValue("new value");
    cobj->SetNumber(100);
    delete cobj;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Child* cobj = new Child();
    Func(cobj);
    cout<<"value: "<<cobj->GetValue()<<endl;
    cout<<"number: "<<cobj->GetNumber()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get `value: number: 100`
Why SetNumber work but SetValue does not?

Comment: You have undefined behavior here as you delete the object inside `Func` but then use it in `main` - the `dynamic_cast` doesn't give you a new instance. Your whole code "feels wrong" - if you are doing OO properly you don't need the `dynamic_cast` at all...

Comment: @John3136 Doesn't SetValue() affect `Parent* obj`? because obj and cobj refer to the same location?

Comment: @JalalJeberi Yes it does. But in `Func` you `delete cobj;` so now it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @John3136 I don't need that `cobj` in `Func` body. `obj` and outer `cobj` both hold the pointer to the same location. I have updated the question. What about the `SetNumber`?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. You don't understand dynamic memory allocation. You are deleting the object being pointed to, not "the pointer" - the pointer still has a value, but now what it points to is "gone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete the object and then continue to access it. This causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939), which means anything may happen.

You can fix the code by removing the line `delete cobj;`.  However you should also check that the result of the `dynamic_cast` is not null before dereferencing it.

In case it is unclear, the `delete` expression deletes the object being pointed to. There is no such concept as "delete the pointer".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with inheritance or function parameters. The problematic code can be reduced to:

```
Child* cobj = new Child();
cobj->SetValue("new value");
delete cobj;
cobj->GetValue();
```

The last two lines are the problem. `delete cobj` destroys the object, but `cobj->GetValue()` still tries to use it. This code has undefined behavior.

To fix the code, you need to remove either `delete cobj` or the `GetValue()` call. In any case, don't try to use an object after it has been destroyed.